# Parse.com Android PushService.setDefaultPushCallback not working

Tags: android, eclipse, parse-platform

Using Parse 1.5.1

Hi, 
the device receives Push notifications, but the
 PushService.setDefaultPushCallback to call a specific class is not working at all. 
Since the app is running in FragmentActivity I had to use getApplicationContext instead of 'this' and run it inside a thread.

Any ideas on how to make this work using FragmentActivity?

The code:

```
     public class Application extends android.app.Application {

   Parse.initialize(mykey,..
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {     
              PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(getApplicationContext(), PushActivity.class);
                ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        }
    }).start();
```